# Get previous value of state in Composable - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

assume my code looks like this

```
@Composable
fun ExampleList() {
    val tickers by exampleViewModel.tickers.observeAsState()
    LazyColumn() {
        items(items = tickers) { ticker ->
            ExampleItem(ticker)
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun ExampleItem(ticker: Ticker) {
    Text(text= ticker.lastPrice)
}
```

is there anyway to get previous value of ticker in ExampleItem Compose everytime ticker is updated?
I'm wondering if there's something like componentDidUpdate in React Native

Answer (score 8):

While the answer is technically correct, the first example renders too many times and I did not understand the second example unfortunately.

So I got back to `React` to see how it is done there and it is explained very good [here](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/):

This is what the hook (`remember` function as you will) looks like (for the curious):

```
function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable ...
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref: any = useRef<T>();
  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes
  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}
```

The same idea can be implemented in compose un a reusable way (it is important that the `@Composable` should not be rerendered when setting the previous value):

```
/**
 * Returns a dummy MutableState that does not cause render when setting it
 */
@Composable
fun <T> rememberRef(): MutableState<T?> {
    // for some reason it always recreated the value with vararg keys,
    // leaving out the keys as a parameter for remember for now
    return remember() {
        object: MutableState<T?> {
            override var value: T? = null

            override fun component1(): T? = value

            override fun component2(): (T?) -> Unit = { value = it }
        }
    }
}
```

and the actual `rememberPrevious`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> rememberPrevious(
    current: T,
    shouldUpdate: (prev: T?, curr: T) -> Boolean = { a: T?, b: T -> a != b },
): T? {
    val ref = rememberRef<T>()

    // launched after render, so the current render will have the old value anyway
    SideEffect {
        if (shouldUpdate(ref.value, current)) {
            ref.value = current
        }
    }

    return ref.value
}
```

`key` values can be added to the `remember` function, but I've found that the `remember` did not work in my case, as it always rerendered even when no `keys` were passed in.

Usage:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SomeComponent() {

    ...
    val prevValue = rememberPrevious(currentValue)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that I could get last value of ticker by using `remember {mutableStateOf}` as below:

```
var lastTicker by remember { mutableStateOf(ticker)}

SideEffect {
   if (lastTicker != ticker) {
     // compare lastTicker to current ticker before assign new value
   
     lastTicker = ticker
   }
}
```

by using `remember { mutableStateOf(ticker)}`, I can persist value of ticker throught recomposition.

then inside SideEffect I can use lastTicker value ( to compare last ticker and current ticker in my case) before assign it to new value to use for next composition

or using `derivedStateOf` to watch ticker change only, avoid recomposition

```
val compareValue by remember(ticker) {
    derivedStateOf {
        // compare lastTicker to current ticker before assign new value

        lastTicker = ticker
       // return value
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `remember(ticker)` already computes only if the `ticker` changes (that's the whole idea of keys). So the `derivedStateOf` here does functionally nothing