# Apply alpha after scrolling part of the screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, parallax, android-jetpack-compose-list

I have an `Image` as a background. I want that after scrolling up to 1.5x the height of the screen, the alpha value of the Composable start changing. his is the logic that seems correct to me:

```
val contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0.0 ? 0.0 : scrollView.contentOffset.y
val backgroundAlpha = (contentOffsetAbsolute / (screenHeight * 1.5))
```

However, I don't know how to get the screen size in Jetpack Compose, or check if it's already 1.5x of the screen size, and also how to manipulate the alpha of the image so that it starts to disappear.

Below, you can see the code in question and the image I have as a background:

```
        val list = mutableListOf<String>().apply {
            for (i in 0..1000) {
                add("Item $i")
            }
        }

        setContent {
        // Decorations omitted for question-readability 
                        Image(
                            painter = ...,                              
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,                               
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        )

                        LazyColumn {
                            items(list.size) { index ->
                                Text(text = list[index], modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
                            }
         }
```

The following's the image, if it adds any significance to the question.

[image]

Comment: Is your question just how you get the screen dimensions? There's plenty of questions on that already present on the site. Also, that's a hella nice gradient!

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper Thanks, I'll pass this message on to the designer xD
As for your question, my question is how to make the logic to change the background alpha as I scroll

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
```

or something like this?

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { 
        
    }
) { //...// }
```

though I haven't tried using `onGloballyPositioned{...}` on a parent layout or a `Surface` yet

Comment: What would I put inside onGlobalPositioned?

Comment: You'll get something you can use to check a `composable` size from `onGloballyPositioned`, but I would recommend just doing the first approach

Comment: But how do I get the how much was scrolled? @z.y

Comment: Compose provides `rememberLazyListState()` that you can supply to any type of `LazyList` and access scroll information,  `val listState = rememberLazyListState() LazyColumn(state = listState) {...} `, also, please have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333935/current-scroll-position-value-in-pixels-in-lazycolumn-jetpack-compose